# Iteratively subsetting pandas chunks with .duplicated() gives me empty arrays

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I am reading in a large csv in chunks with Pandas.  I subset each chunk to see if there are duplicated timestamps:

```
for c in chunks:
    dups= c.duplicated(subset='Timestamp')
    dups= dups[dups==True]
    print(dups)
```

When I print dups, I get the following:

```
255    True
dtype: bool
Series([], dtype: bool)

2295    True
2687    True
dtype: bool
Series([], dtype: bool)
```

I understand why I am getting the indexes where the condition is true, but why the empty Series objects?

Comment: can you include the print statements in your questions?

Comment: Sure, sorry about that:

Comment: Sure, sorry about that, I just put the above code into a function:
<code>
def is_duplicated(x):
    dups = c.duplicated(subset='Timestamp')
    dups = dups[dups==True].index.tolist()
    print(dups)
<code>
So then, the above from my first question becomes:
for c in chunks:
      is_duplicated(c)

This gives me output such as posted above:
[62076, 62829]
[]
[65448, 65921]
[]
[67158]
[68346, 68581, 68922]
Again, I don't understand why I get the empty arrays; I'm guessing that it initializes an array for each chunk, and if there is no match, it simply doesn't fill that array?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, the line `dups= dups[dups==True]` returns an empty `Series` if `dups` is all `False`. If you don't want to print it when it's empty you could include a check for `len(dups) > 0`:

```
for c in chunks:
    dups= c.duplicated(subset='Timestamp')
    dups= dups[dups==True]
    if len(dups) > 0:
        print(dups)
```